# unsafe ownership on homedir

Tags: 12.04, permissions

I am trying to run gpg on Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit LTS

I get the following error:

```
gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on homedir `/home/jeffrey/.repoconfig/gnupg'
gpg: failed to create temporary file `/home/jeffrey/.repoconfig/gnupg/.#lk0x7508c0.jeffrey-Satellite-M645.23486': Permission denied
gpg: keyblock resource `/home/jeffrey/.repoconfig/gnupg/pubring.gpg': general error
gpg: Signature made Fri 01 Mar 2013 11:36:42 AM CST using DSA key ID 920F5C65
gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found
error: could not verify the tag 'v1.12.2'
```

My current permissions are:

```
jeffrey@jeffrey-Satellite-M645:~$ ls -dl
drwxr-xr-x 37 jeffrey jeffrey 4096 Aug 15 10:56 .
```

What should the permissions be set to?

Please advise.

Comment: what is `/home/jeffrey/.repoconfig/gnupg`?

Answer (score 1):

Everything is ok! The error:

```
error: could not verify the tag 'v1.12.2'
```

does nothing have to do with your current permissions which are set ok!

Search on google for "Can't check signature: public key not found" to see where your problem is.

Comment: @RaduRadeanu are you certain that the second line in the message where permission denied is not relevant?

Comment: @RaduRadeanu I found the answer.  I was not logged in as root into Terminal.  Once I did, the error went away and repo installed correctly.  But, I still want to know what to do with `WARNING unsafe ownership on homedir`

Comment: @RaduRadeanu  If you answer the question on `unsafe ownership on homedir` too  then I can in good conscience do so.  In the absence of that, I have marked your answer as useful.  :^)

Comment: @AndroidAddict Well, now you can answer yourself... Why should I do this when you solved your problem?

Comment: @RaduRadeanu The question is the `unsafe ownership on homedir` specifically what the permissions should be.  You aided me to get Gnupg working for the repo, but my post is still technically unanswered.  :^)

Comment: @AndroidAddict You showed us only the error/warning... I'm not a guru to guess what command did you runned with or without root privileges. So, I'm sure that in this case only you can provide the "technical" answer.

Comment: @RaduRadeanu The system has one user, me, and that was the context I was running under and the command I ran was `repo init`.  I ran this command from the `/home/user` directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo chown -R yourusername ~/android/system/.repo
```

Where `yourusername`  is your Username which you use to login.